# Using Thrift in iOS

Tags: ios, thrift

Is there good documentation for using thrift in iOS? I am having trouble getting started and figuring out how to apply thrift to iOS.

Answer (score 5):

Just stumbled on this question,
this tutorial should be a good starting point
http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC

Comment: having trouble getting this tutorial to align with the brew install of thrift. looking for more contemporary docs.

Comment: The tutorial is not very useful. The library doesn't look well designed for iOS.